# Как перебрать массив с определенными значениями?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой массив:

```
var arr = [53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 0, 1, 2];
var arr2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
```

Через какую функцию его пропустить чтобы на выводе был такой массив?

```
var arr = ['', '', 55, '', '', '', '', 0, '', ''];
var arr2 = ['', 5, '', '', '', '', 10, '', '', '', '', 15, ''];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var arr = [53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 0, 1, 2];
var arr2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];

const checkDivBy5 = i => i % 5? '' : i;

arr = arr.map(checkDivBy5);
arr2 = arr2.map(checkDivBy5);

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 0, 1, 2];
var arr2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];

console.log(arr.map(function(element){ return element % 5 === 0 ? element.toString() : ''; }));
console.log(arr2.map(function(element){ return element % 5 === 0 ? element.toString() : ''; }));
```

Comment: А для чего toString ?) В ожидаемом массиве из вопроса остались именно числа.

Comment: в приципе незачем. Только для наглядности. Привычка из типизированных языков